# if statements within batch scripts to deploy wireless profiles to windows computers using netsh

Tags: windows, batch-file, wireless, netsh

I would like to automate the deployment of wireless profiles.

The scenario is, there are Windows computers already connected to network A. I would like to deploy to all computers a new wireless profile for network B with the exception of those computers that are already connected to network A.

Below is a rough idea of what I think I need, however i'm struggling to find the correct code.

```
netsh wlan show profile | find "wireless profile name"
if exist "wireless profile name"
    do nothing
else
    netsh wlan add profile filename="2nd wireless profile"
```

I know the top line works, the part I am struggling with is the if statement and how to check the result of find with the exist function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `find.exe` for this task, just use the returned `ErrorLevel` from asking to see the profile:

```bat
"%__AppDir__%netsh.exe" WLAN Show Profiles Name="wireless profile name">NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 "%__AppDir__%netsh.exe" WLAN Add Profile FileName="2nd wireless profile"
```

If you are positive that the PC's you're running this on have the default entries under `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%`, then you could probably shorten that to:

```bat
NetSH WLAN Show Profiles Name="wireless profile name">NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 NetSH WLAN Add Profile FileName="2nd wireless profile"
```

Comment: So am I right in thinking that if the profile is there the ErrorLevel will be equal to 0, meaning that the If statement does not run? 

Also what is the reason for ">NUL" I want to make sure I fully understand what you've provided as a solution, thanks for the help.

Comment: I wouldn't have answered without a message telling you "this isn't a full solution", if it wasn't, in my opinion, a full solution. To fully understand it, temporarily change the second line to `If ErrorLevel 1 Echo Failed`, then run it. Next try it with `>NUL` removed from the first line. If your tests were performed using a connected network profile, you can repeat that process with a deliberately non existing profile name, (or vice versa). *There should be nothing to stop you from doing that at the Command Prompt, either.*

Comment: That helps the understanding a lot. Thanks Compo.